# Strange behavior with jComboBox

Tags: java, swing, derby, jcombobox, netbeans-8

We have build a project with Netbeans 8.2 in java for a School project and we have created a form where it has a JcomboBox that it's populated from a derby database.
The application on it's first run downloads a movie list from an web api in json and stores it in derby together with movie genres. Then the user can create favorite lists and assign movies selected from different genres to the favorite lists.

The problem is when you open the form to assign movies on the lists that the user created the JComboBox that has the genre selection appears empty. If you quit the application and reopen it the JComboBox is populated correctly.

The code of the renderer of JComboBox is the below:

```
 genreCombo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value instanceof Genre) {
                Genre mec = (Genre)value;
                setText(mec.getName());
            }
            return this;
        }
    });
```

from the debugging I see that the value variable that holds the genres returns with a null movieList when the form not appears correct and when the form appears correct value variable holds a movieList with all the movies downloaded and belong to the current genre.
So the setText gets null values.

Any idea what it is causing this?